# What is the maximum charging voltage of a Li-Ion battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I will design a charging circuit for an **ICR26650** 3.7 V Li-Ion battery. I'm considering using the **BQ24070** chip in the design. The battery charging voltage of this chip is given as 4.2 V. [Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24070.pdf?ts=1678086469774&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

I know that 3.7 V Li-Ion batteries charge smoothly up to 4.2 V. But what I'm wondering is, can the Li-Ion battery stay at 4.2 V voltage for a long time? Will it damage the battery?

Answer (score 1):

The standard Li-Ion chemistry is charged to 4.2 V, and then the charge terminated after the charge current drops below a threshold.

If you continue holding the cell voltage at 4.2 V for a long time, even though the current has dropped to a very low value, you **will** damage the battery, plating out lithium in an unusable form.

This charging protocol is a compromise between achieving a good capacity, and a reasonable number of charge cycles. There is no hard and fast limit on either, it's a commercial decision.

Once charging has stopped, the terminal voltage drops. Phone and laptop chargers typically let the voltage drop to 4.1 V, and then top-up to 4.2 V again. This maintenance regime is known to degrade the battery after a few years. I wish laptops had a mode that would hold the batteries at a storage level when on mains power, and only boost them when you asked.

In battery applications where they want a good guarranteed life, cars or satellites for instance, they charge to a much lower voltage. In the former, they often cycle the batteries between 20% and 80% SOC when they are new, in order to have some in reserve to meet their 8 year guarrantees. In the latter, NASA charge their cells to 3.92 V to prolong their on orbit life.

There are lithium cells with a slightly modified chemistry that can be charged to 4.35 V, they are typically called Li-HV.

Personally, I lie to my drill charger that I have Li-Lo cells, and it charges them to 4.1 V. While floating lithiums is controversial, I am presently building a project that will float them at 4.0 V, which I think ought to be better than cycling them between 4.1 V and 4.2 V. I'll see how it goes and report back in a few years.

Comment: If I understood correctly, it would be healthier to charge the Li-Ion battery up to 4V by adjusting the output voltage of my BQ24070 chip. I won't be able to stop charging whenever I want. As soon as the system starts up, my battery will begin to charge and will continue to charge continuously until the system shuts down. System shutdown is dependent on user usage. In this case, fixing the battery charge voltage to 4V is the healthiest solution?

Comment: Can I find a Li-Ion battery with a nominal voltage of 4.2V? Will it solve my problem?

Comment: @harmonica It depends what you want. The BQ24070 should 'just work' for you. It has a nominal recharge threshold of 0.1 V, which from my very brief reading suggests it will automatically cycle the battery between 4.2 V and 4.1 V. This will result in a battery life of < 5 years. if you want longer life, you need lower charge voltage, or a different chemistry. There are no batteries with nominal 4.2 V (except perhaps two lead acid in series!). `will it solve my problem?` I don't know what your problem is, you need to clearly define it to get a good answer.

Comment: @harmonica it doesn't look like that BQ chip can be programmed to voltages other than 4.2 V, so you're stuck with the 'high capacity - a few years life' compromise that markets seem to expect users to buy. Let's be fair, users do buy that compromise by the gazillion, so the markets are commercially justified.